# Why can't I send data properly to Controller?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, vuejs3

i have a problem with sending data from vue component through api to controller.
I have a function like that in component (this.selectedItems is an array of objects):

```js
async getEntries() {
  try {
    this.projectEntries = await this.$API.projects.getEntries(
      this.currentPartyId,
      this.selectedItems,
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    this.$toast.error(e.response.data.message);
  }
},
```

It is a method. That function sends data to global api:

```js
getEntries(partyId, projects) {
 return $axios.get(`party/${partyId}/projects/entries`, { data: { projects } });
},
```

My function in Laravel Controller looks like that:

```php
/**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Party $party
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function getEntries(Request $request, Party $party): JsonResponse
    {
        // $this->checkPermissions([
        //     ProjectsEntityPermission::childCode(ListPermission::class)
        // ], $party);

        $entries = [];

        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info($party);
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info($request);
        foreach ($request->projects as $project) {
            $project = Project::findOrFail($project->id);
            $entries[$project->id] = $project->workLog();
        }

        return response()->json([
            'data' => $entries
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

That's my route in api.php:

```php
    Route::group([
        'prefix' => 'projects'
    ], function($router) {
        Route::get('/statuses', [ProjectController::class, 'getStatuses']);
        Route::delete('/delete', [ProjectController::class, 'manyDelete']);
        Route::get('/entries', [ProjectController::class, 'getEntries']);
    });
```

It should have an $request that contains this.selectedItems from getEntries function, but it tells me that $request is null. Why?

I want to achieve that Controller will return an array of $key(project.id) -> $value(projectEntries) pairs for specific passed projects. I am using Vue 2.0 and Laravel.

What i tried:
Changing api to:

```js
  getEntries(partyId, {
    params,
  }) {
    return $axios.get(`party/${partyId}/projects/entries`, {
      params,
    });
  },
```

And changing getEntries function to:

```js
      try {
        this.projectEntries = await this.$API.projects.getEntries(
          this.currentPartyId,
          {
            projects: this.selectedItems,
          },
        );
      }
```

Comment: What does your route look like? I also might remember that axios is like axios.get('example.com/test', {params: projects}} instead of data.

Comment: @FryingPan Added api.php route. If it should look like that in axios, should i change getEntries function too?

Comment: @FryingPan Added my changes to post. Still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's a problem with GET request with body, try with this:

```
getEntries(partyId, projects) {
  return $axios.get(`party/${partyId}/projects/entries`, {
    params: { projects: projects.map(p => p.id).join(",") }
  });
}
```

and in Laravel:

```
$projectIds = explode(",", $request->query('projects'));
foreach ($projectIds as $projectId) {
    $project = Project::findOrFail($projectId);
    $entries[$project->id] = $project->workLog();
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to send multiple id's in a query string.